# Que palabra reservada hay en python para convertir en constante cualquier variable?

Tags: python

Es que quiero que variables sean constantes como "final" o "const" en otros lenguajes de programación como C++ o java pero no e encontrado en python.

Answer (score 0):

No existen constantes en Python. Simplemente se suelen definir con un nombre en mayúsculas: `CONSTANTE_BLA = 10`.

Comment: Si pero es facil cambiarla no es una constante

Comment: Si, es fácil cambiarla porque no es una constante. No hay constantes en Python, es una decisión de los creadores del lenguaje. Si hay convenciones y si uno encuentra en un programa en Python una variable cuyo nombre está en mayúsculas puede esperar que su valor no cambie en la ejecución. Sin embargo no hay nada que lo impida.

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque C++ y Python (por ejemplo) pertenecen a dos clases diferentes de lenguajes.

Uno es de tipeo estático y otro dinámico.

En un lenguaje de tipeo estático, el verificador es capaz de inferir el tipo de cada expresión y chequear si esta satisface la declaración durante la fase de compilación.

En un lenguaje de tipeo dinámico, la información del tipo de la expresión no es definida sino hasta tiempo de ejecución.

'**const**' es un modificador. Restringe el acceso a una variable a la hora de modificarla. Sería un poco ineficiente chequear tal restricción en tiempo de ejecución en un lenguaje de tipeo dinámico.

Comment: Pero se puede encontrar la forma de utilizar una clase para convertir a cada objecto que este dentro de la clase en constante y así se pueda utilizar en un programa completo? creo que ahí están involucrados los métodos mágicos                                                                                         
´          __len__,__self__,__add__,etc ´